# Nginx, how to allow IP:PORT requests

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

What's the proper way to configure Nginx to allow IP:PORT requests like this:

```
//App is deployed on 8086
http://X.X.X.X:8086/?a=xxx&b=yyy&c=zzz ((http requests))
over TCP or UDP
```

```
//Another app is deployed on 5050
http://X.X.X.X:5050/postRequest (http requests)
over TCP or UDP
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       listen         80 default_server;
       listen         [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name    _;
       root           /home/ubuntu/var/www/html;
       index          index.html index.htm default.html;
       access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access.log mycustomformat;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add new serverblock for each port on your configuration. You can also set different root directory for each port. For example:

```
server {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       listen         80 default_server;
       listen         [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name    _;
       root           /home/ubuntu/var/www/html;
       index          index.html index.htm default.html;
       access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access.log mycustomformat;
..
..
}
server {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       listen         8086;
       listen         [::]:8086;
       server_name    _;
       root           /home/ubuntu/var/www/your8086dir;
       index          index.html index.htm default.html;
       access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access-8086.log mycustomformat;
..
..
}
server {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       listen         5050;
       listen         [::]:5050;
       server_name    _;
       root           /home/ubuntu/var/www/your5050dir;
       index          index.html index.htm default.html;
       access_log /etc/nginx/logs/access-5050.log mycustomformat;
..
..
}
```

Comment: That is what problem is. We want this to be dynamic. There can be multiple apps deployed. We cannot always go in config and add new block.

Comment: you can write bash, python, etc script to create server block and then reload or restart nginx service